# store a calculated value in the datastore or just calculate it on the fly

Tags: python, database, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I writing an app in python for google app engine where each user can submit a post and each post has a ranking which is determined by its votes and comment count.  The ranking is just a simple calculation based on these two parameters.  I am wondering should I store this value in the datastore (and take up space there) or just simply calculate it every time that I need it.  Now just fyi the posts will be sorted by ranking so that needs to be taken into account.

I am mostly thinking for the sake of efficiency and trying to balance if I should try and save the datastore room or save the read/write quota.

I would think it would be better to simply store it but then I need to recalculate and rewrite the ranking value every time anyone votes or comments on the post.

Any input would be great.

Comment: When considering efficiency, think about the additional work needed to store the data.  Generally, I/O is a bigger constraint than processing power.  As such, I'd tend to go with calculations on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about storing the ranking as a property in the post.  That would make sense for querying/sorting wouldn't it.

If you store the ranking at the same time (meaning in the same entitiy) as you store the votes/comment count, then the only increase in write cost would be for the index.  (ok initial write cost too but that is what 2 [very small anyway]).

You need to do a database operation everytime anyone votes or comments on the post anyway right!?!  How else can to track votes/comments?

Actually though, I imagine you will get into use text search to find data in the posts. If so, I would look into maybe storing the ranking as a property in the search index and using it to rank matching results.

Don't we need to consider how you are selecting the posts to display.  Is ranking by votes and comments the only criteria?

Comment: okay so there isn't much difference in writing three properties of a entity as opposed to two?  it isn't a 50% increase?  I suppose not but that's good to know.  There are categories but within each category the posts are only sorted by either creation date or ranking

Comment: WHY index votes/comments?  For sure not votes!  If you are indexing comments, isn't text search the way to go anyway?  Save your write expense anyway by not indexing what you don't look up by.  Anyway, costs are (1 Write + 4 Writes per modified indexed property value + 2 Writes per modified composite index value).  Ref. http://blog.xam.de/2011/11/analysis-of-datastore-operation-cost.html

Comment: what do you mean why index votes? votes are just a property of my post entity, sorry if I wasn't clear on that.  How would I attach comments to a post if they aren't indexed?

Comment: I mean set votes to NOT be indexed.  Indexed properties take 4 writes on an update.  How are you storing the comments?  This is what I don't understand.  Are you storing a key to comments in the post entity?  Are you filtering by a post key kept in the comments entity?  Of course the comments entity key needs to be indexed to look it up.  Anyway, I would try what Dave W. Smith suggested and periodically update your entity with new votes / rating from your tally in memcache.

Comment: well I haven't actually done it yet so I am not currently doing any of those, I am just trying to find out the best way to do it.  what I am planning on doing right now is using the postID as the key

Comment: You plan to use the postID in the comments entity?  I would be wary of that.  If a post has 100 comments you might end up with high read costs.  Maybe you can combine comments in on entity.  Anyway, how would you know how many comments there are?  That is why I suggested storing the ranking value.  Otherwise you would end up querying all your comments for posts in a category just to decide which posts are the highest ranked.  memcache ongoing tally + stored value seems like what you need. You have to think about it.  Maybe it would make sense to store the ranking by category.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear on that.  I am planning on tying the comments to the posts by their postID, not the commentID. as far as doing the ranking I am leaning towards what you have suggested by just holding the rankings in memcache and updating that memcache when a new comment or upvote comes around and then taking this ranking from memcache and storing it in the database every 100 comments/upvotes or so

Comment: if you need to update the ranking more frequently than you can with one entity, the technique to do that is called shareding counters. You said you'd try memcache though and don't mind possible losing a few votes though so maybe it's not relevant. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Answer (score 1):

Caching is most useful when the calculation is expensive. If the calculation is simple and cheap, you might as well recalculate as needed.

Comment: And I'd prefer caching in memory rather than writing it to a database.  It implies a less permanent state to me than writing to a persistent store.  I also like having it closer to memory and not requiring a network hop to get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're depending on keeping a running vote count in an entity, then you either have to be willing to lose an occasional vote, or you have to use transactions. If you use transactions, you're rate limited as to how many transactions you can do per second. (See the doc on transactions and entity groups). If you're liable to have a high volume of votes, rate limiting can be a problem.

For a low rate of votes, keeping a count in an entity might work fine. But if you any significant peaks in voting rate, storing separate Vote entities that periodically get rolled up into a cached count, perhaps adjusted by (possibly unreliable) incremental counts kept in memcache, might work better for you.

It really depends on what you want to optimize for. If you're trying to minimize disk writes by keeping a vote count cached non-transactionally, you risk losing votes.

Comment: are we talking about 1/100 or more like 1/10?  1/100 isn't too much of a problem

Comment: Vote undercounting due to non-transactional get, increment, put is going to depend entirely on the timing of vote arrival. If voting is relatively infrequent, you may be fine. If you're doing something that will involve clusters of people voting nearly simultaneously, you're at risk.